# Time Based Workflow Field Update Action Order of Execution

Tags: time-dependent-workflow, process-builder

If I have a Time Dependent Workflow that does a Field Update, what would be the order of execution starting with that field Update?

Will other workflows be trigger by this Field Update?

Example:

Workflow 1: Time Dependent Workflow that is scheduled to run 10 days after something happens to a Case. When triggered, Time Dependent Workflow will update field X to be "hello".

Workflow 2: Everytime Field X is updated to be "hello", send an email.

What will happen if the Time Dependent Workflow runs? (Assuming Field X is not "hello" at the time this happens) Will the email from Workflow 2 go out?

Here is what I am experiencing, but I want to verify that this is the situation in all cases:

Field X will be set to "hello" and Workflow 2 is not being triggered.

Question 2: If Workflow 2 was a Process (New Process builder) instead of a Workflow, would that cause the email to be sent?

Thanks ahead for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1 : If the "field update" of your Time based workflow has "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules After Field Change" as true, then it will execute all the workflows again.

Answer 2 : Since all workflow rules on the associated object are re-evaluated. Any workflow rules whose criteria are met as a result of the field update will be triggered..

Time-dependent actions aren't executed for a reevaluated workflow rule in the following situations:

The re-evaluated workflow rule’s immediate actions cause the record to no longer meet the workflow rule criteria.

An Apex after trigger that is executed as a result of a workflow or approvals action causes the record to no longer meet the workflow rule criteria.